# Node --debug-brk app.js not functioning

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to debug my app but something is stopping the app from actually firing up when I use --debug-brk flag.

Here's my output normally:

```
/usr/local/bin/node app.js
Express server listening on port 3000
Connected to database HackRegDb
```

Here's what happens when I run --debug-brk (with a breakpoint at a point in the code that won't be hit on initial startup)

```
/usr/local/bin/node --debug-brk=59763 app.js
debugger listening on port 59763
```

See, no "server listening" portion.  The code is the same obviously, and there's no breakpoint before that is spit out.

For reference, here's my app.js file:

```
var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , members = require('./routes/members')
  , teams = require('./routes/teams')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.session());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/members', members.list);
app.get('/teams', teams.list);
app.post('/members', members.add);
app.post('/teams', teams.add);
app.put('/members/:id', members.update);
app.put('/teams/:id', teams.update);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you find the cause for the problem? I have exactly the same issue but with cloud9 running locally ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers. The problem seems to have been resolved through one of the many updates from JetBrains. I'm able to debug properly and without issues now.

Answer (score 10):

`--debug-brk=` stops the node program on the first line, meaning it will break before starting the server. You can then connect your debugger and hit Continue to run the program.

You can use `--debug=` to start the debugger but not break at the start. So if you have a `debugger` line somewhere in asynchronous code, it will still break when it hits it if your debugger is connected.

Comment: This didn't seem to help, I'm discussing the issue with JetBrains since it should be built in (and I shouldn't have to really know about  these flags).  Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Weird enough but this is what helped me.

I run the same command line but without `-brk`.

```
/usr/local/bin/node --debug=59763 app.js
```

The app finished successfully. And then the subsequent runs of the `--debug-brk` worked fine.

```
/usr/local/bin/node --debug-brk=59763 app.js
```

Answer (score 0):

in jetbrains PhpStorm,

after starting your node app, near the debug tools at the bottom left. there is a lightning bolt (toggle break on exception).

for me un-selecting that option that fixed my problem.